# System::IO::Directory::GetDirectories( "c: vs c:\\")

Tags: c++, .net

Just being curious,

I had the problem that I used `System::IO::Directory::GetDirectories("c:")` instead of `System::IO::Directory::GetDirectories("c:\\")`.

It ended up retrieving directories from `"C:\Windows\System32"`. If I didn't use the backslash with other drives I ended up with directories I didn't know existed.

Can someone tell me why is this happening? Is there a pattern? When is it used?

Answer (score 4):

When you omit the backslash at the beginning of the path (or after the drive letter), the path is considered *relative* to the *current directory*. You can get the value of the *current directory* with `System::IO::Directory::GetCurrentDirectory()` method and you can change it with `System::IO::Directory::SetCurrentDirectory(path)` method.

To clarify consider this: When current directory is `C:\Windows`, the path `C:test.txt` is equivalent to `C:\Windows\test.txt`.

[`GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) method returns all the directories in the specified path, even hidden or system directories (which you normally do not see in Windows Explorer). So I guess you are talking about system directories in other drives like `System Volume Information` and `$RECYCLE.BIN`.

It is good to mention that in a Windows shell (cmd.exe) we can have separate *current directories* for each drive. When you run:

```
C:\Windows\System32> cd d:\Temp
C:\Windows\System32> dir c:
```

you get the contents of `C:\Windows\System32` and then when you run:

```
C:\Windows\System32> dir d:
```

you get the contents of `D:\Temp`

Comment: +1 I forgot about the relative path. But what I still don't get is this: GetCurrentDirectory returned the project folder "j:\files\solutrion\project" (j:\ is the drive where the project is stored.). When I used the letters of the drives that weren't ready an exception was thrown, when I used the letters of the drives that were ready I was redirected to some strange locations. The hidden files are set to visible, so I can see everything that a directory contains. This means there is a difference between (drive): and (drive):\

Comment: I do not see your issue in my machine. When querying other drives, I get the contents of the drive's root.

Comment: even without the backslash?

Comment: Yes. What is the output when you run `GetCurrentDirectory("D:")` for example? What is the directory you get the contents of?

Comment: When I checked `d:`, I got the files on that particular drive, including some extra content I've never seen before. `c:` brings me to `C:\Windows\System32`. Both of these are internal hard drives. External hard drives and flash drives show the proper content.

Comment: What are those extra content?

Comment: It appears that `d:` and `d:\ ` give the same content (which I can't find in the folder by the way, but that's another issue). I thought it were only internal hard drives, but it in only `c:` which redirects to another folder.